# Meaning of spark.sql.sources.provider in TBLPROPERTIES

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I create a table in spark over parquet using `saveAsTable` and then view the `TBLPROPERTIES` of the table, I see one of the properties is `spark.sql.sources.provider=parquet`. I couldn't find this property anywhere in either the documentation or the spark source itself, and I don't understand how it affects the table. Is there documentation anywhere on `TBLPROPERTIES` that spark appends to the table in general?

Comment: What's the spark version?  it's just metadata of table, you will get other details also like InputFormat, OutputFormat, Owner etc

Answer (score 1):

Spark SQL stores some Spark-specific table properties using `spark.sql` prefix (e.g. table statistics for Cost-Based Optimization).

Among them is `spark.sql.sources.provider` that is the way to tell Spark SQL what data source (table) format to use to load a (catalog) table.

Comment: Why does spark need to append this property to the table? There is no such property when the table is created through a `CREATE TABLE` query (as opposed to using `saveAsTable`). Also, are these table properties documented anywhere or are these internal workings that you have to read the source code to understand?